# How do I get the Mahopons and the Megapons?

Tags: patapon-2

In Patapon 2, I am having some difficulties figuring out which existing fighters of my Patapon army can be upgraded to discover the Mahopons, Toripons and the Megapons. So far, I have:

Yaripon, Tatepon, Yumipon, Kibapon, Dekapon, and Robopon. Help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to unlock them through the level grid system. As far as I remember, Mahopon it is unlocked after you unlock the penguin Patapon.